# Linear Algebra problem on basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

The question is "Let $x_k$ denote the vector in $\mathbb R^n$ whose first $k-1$ coordinates are $0$ and the last $n-k+1$ coordinates are $1$. Show that the set $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ is a basis in $\mathbb R^n$".
I am a beginner and I am able to do this only for sets that are explicitly defined and not infinite sets like these. Any help on how to solve this is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: That's a finite set, and it is explicitly defined. How about doing an example: when $n=3$ the vectors are $(1,1,1)$, $(0,1,1)$ and $(0,0,1)$. Can you see why this is a basis?

Comment: as it is linearly independent. all three rows dont depend on each other?

Answer (score 3):

The matrix $A=(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)$ is lower-triangular with only $1$'s on the diagonal. Hence $\det(A)=1$, and hence the column vectors $x_i$ form a basis.

Comment: Thank You. I understand it better now.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $x_k-x_{k+1}=e_{k+1}$ where $\{e_1,..., e_n\}$ is the standard basis.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathscr{B}:=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ is a set of $n$ vectors and $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space, then we have that $\mathscr{B}$ is a basis iff $\mathscr{B}$ is linearly independent. Thus we only need to show that $\mathscr{B}$ is linearly independent. Let $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ be real numbers such that
$$
c_1x_1+\cdots+c_nx_n=0.
$$
Since
$$0 = c_1x_1+\cdots+c_nx_n
= \begin{pmatrix}
c_1 \\ c_1+c_2 \\
\vdots \\
c_1+\cdots+c_n
\end{pmatrix},
$$
we deduce that $c_1=c_2=\cdots=c_n=0$. Therefore $\mathscr{B}$ is linearly independent, and consequently is a basis for $\mathbb{R}$.